# Ren-C error:; "word is bound relative to context not on stack"

Tags: runtime-error

I am using the [experimental Ren-C implementation](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c) of Rebol3.  I can't understand this error:

```
f: func [x /local y][
    emit: func [x] [y]
    y: 0
    forall x [emit f []]
    0
]

f [0 0]
```

> ** Script error: y word is bound relative to context not on stack
>
> ** Where: emit forall f do catch either either --anonymous-- do trap either --anonymous--
>
> ** Near: ... y

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138621/discussion-on-question-by-giuliolunati-rebol3-ren-c-implementation-error-wor).

Comment: Also, consider using [meta] for discussions on tagging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a by-product of what is known as [specific binding](https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c/wiki/Relative-Binding-and-FRAME!-Internals), and is behaving as expected.

The issue is that since you are using FUNC instead of FUNCTION for `f`, `emit` is not a local of f.  Each time you run `f`, you are overwriting a global `emit`, while `y` is local to each specific instantiation.

So the global emit, which gets overwritten on each call, winds up getting a version of the emit function whose concept of y is relative to calls to f which no longer exist.

If you really intend to create a new local to hold a unique function--with a unique concept of y--each time it runs, you may do so explictly:

```
f: func [x /local y emit][
    emit: func [x] [y]
    y: 0
    forall x [emit f []]
    0
]

f [0 0]
```

Or implicitly:

```
f: function [x] [
    emit: func [x] [y]
    y: 0
    forall x [emit f []]
    0
]

f [0 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it!